# Laravel Passport saying refresh token is invalid

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, refresh-token

So, have set up an API in one Laravel application using Passport, which I’m consuming in another Laravel app. Almost all is working well, but when I try to use a refresh token, I get the message on the Passport side that the refresh token was invalid. I am storing the refresh token in a database field 2000 characters in length and wondering if that’s not enough, or if something in my refresh function is wrong. Any ideas?

```
private function refreshToken($token) {
    $http = $this->newClient();
    try {
        $response = $http->post($this->_url . '/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
                'refresh_token' => $token->refresh_token,
                'client_id' => $this->_clientId,
                'client_secret' => $this->_secretKey,
                'scope' => 'products orders',
            ],
        ]);
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        Log::error($ex);
        $token = $this->newToken();
        return $token;
    }
    $token = Token::saveToken($response);
    return $token;
}
```

Comment: Does passport use JWTs for refresh tokens? If so, have you tried inspecting the JWT to see if it has the correct data to get a new access token?

Comment: I don't think it's JWTs exactly, but something similar. I thought I'd checked to make sure the refresh token is included (90% sure it is), but I'll check again in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured out what was actually happening that was causing problems, and it wasn't the refresh token being invalid. That meant it was just expired, and the code is set up to get a new token in that case. Instead, the problem was coming when I'd check a token for expiration, but between that check and the call using it, the token would have expired. So, I added some padding to the expiration check, and now it's working smoothly. Live and learn. :)